# Upload an entire XML file to Azure Mobile Services

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have an XML with 25,000 objects that I want to transition to the cloud instead of keeping it local. Buuuuuut I have no idea how to get the XML document into the service, preferably I want it in the SQL database that comes with the service. I know how to upload from the app but with 25,000 objects the service times out. I am sure there is something I just cant find the documentation on.

```
    private async void bw_Worker(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(card x in cardsList)
        {
            await App.MobileService.GetTable<card>().InsertAsync(x);
        }
    }
```

It gets just past 7500 then times out. I am running it in a background worker. I couldn't find any such limits on that so I just imagined its a process that takes too long to complete.

Comment: Could you show the code you use that times out?

Comment: I updated the post to include the code. Its really simple